# How to fix http redirects with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-redirect

I have a webpage where http redirects are a bit broken.

The current behavior is this:

www.example.com, example.com, http://www.example.com, http://example.com, https://www.example.com all gets redirected to https://www.example.com

and

https://example.com gets an error saying refused to connect.

I want the behavior to be like this:

example.com, http://example.com, https://example.com redirects to https://example.com

www.example.com, http://www.example.com, https://www.example.com redirects to https://www.example.com

Here is my Nginx config file

```
server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server;
       server_name example.com www.example.com;
       return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Reason is because I want these links to work

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=example.com

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.example.com

https://hstspreload.org/?domain=example.com

https://hstspreload.org/?domain=www.example.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two independent issues:

---

1. Your requests all redirect to `example.com`, regardless of which specific domain is originally accessed.

This happens because the [`$server_name`](http://nginx.org/r/$server_name) variable that you are using is effectively a static variable in a given `server` context, and has a very distant relationship to [`$http_host`](http://nginx.org/r/$http_).

The correct way would be to use [**`$host`**](http://nginx.org/r/$host) instead (which is basically `$http_host` with some edge-corner cleanups).

---

2. You're receiving connection issues when trying to contact `https://example.com`, but not `https://www.example.com`.

There is not enough information in your question to pinpoint the exact origin of this problem.

It can be a DNS issue (`A`/`AAAA` records of `example.com` set at an IP address where appropriate bindings to the `https` port aren't made).

It could be an issue with the mismatched certificate:

- Does your certificate cover both `example.com` and `www.example.com`?  If not, then you can't have both.
- If you have separate certificates, you may also need to acquire separate IP addresses, or risk preventing a significant number of users from accessing your site due to lack of [SNI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#name_based_https_servers).

---

As of note, it should also be pointed out that it is generally a sloppy practice to not have a unified notation on the way your site is accessed.  Especially if SEO is of any concern to you, the best practice is to decide on whether you want to go with or without `www`, and stick to it.

Comment: My certificate does cover both example.com and www.example.com. And your right, for the sake of SEO, I want everything to get redirected to https://www.example.com. So what should my config file look like then assuming I have my DNS setup correctly?

Comment: @user299648, don't you already say that everything `http://` is redirected to `https://example.com` with the way things are?  If you want to redirect from `https`, too, you should add something like `if ($host != "example.com") {rewrite ^ https://example.com$request_uri? redirect;}` to the `https` `server` context.

Comment: @user299648, there is no reason for it not to work.  also, if you want us to help you, i'm afraid you'd have to give us a little bit more details of what exactly is not working and what the exact symptoms are.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name www.example.com;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300; includeSubdomains; preload";

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300; includeSubdomains; preload";

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

All your requests will be ultimately routed to https://example.com.
Your ssl certificate should also be valid for https://www.example.com which I note you have said it is.

Comment: @user299648, have you tried the config given above? Should route all your traffic to example.com as you mention you wish to have. Note that the test against the preload adding service should only fail on the max age length with this which is set to 5 mins for this testing stage. You can then bump it up once you are sure you have everything in place.

Comment: @user299648, can you clarify? If the given config is not working for you, there must be something else going on with your site as it is a standard/straightforward setup which has been battle tested.

What errors/results do you get? Can you post your actual current config ... on pastebin for instance? I can say with 100% certainty that a 3-server block config, such as given above, is how you deal with the https redirect on Nginx.

So again, if not working, then some information is missing about your setup. IPTable redirects in effect perhaps?